# RuntimeException while parsing back the byte[] to protocol buffer message instance! (deserialization)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I tried following code for encoding and decoding.

Decoding from byte[] fails, however.

Code:-

```
public static void test(){

    Comment comment = Comment.newBuilder()
            .setCommentBody("This is 1st comment")
            .build();
    byte[] bytes = comment.toByteArray();

    try {
        Comment c = Comment.parseFrom(bytes);
    }
    catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(testing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Exception details:-

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessageLite.java:153)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFrom(AbstractMessage.java:709)
    at paratha.serializers.protocolbuffers.CommentProto$Comment.parseFrom(CommentProto.java:186)
```

Comment: can you show the full stack of the exception?

Comment: this is the full stack I can see..

Answer (score 1):

Are you building Protocol Buffers yourself by any chance? Or perhaps `Comment` itself hasn't compiled properly?

This looks like the kind of exception which is thrown by code built by Eclipse when the compilation has errors, but it builds you class files anyway. It lets you run broken code until you get to the *actual* broken bit, at which point you get an exception like this.

Comment: I just defined my .proto file and got it compiled using protoc and added the generated class files and library to my source folder. I did not compiled protocol buffers using the source code. Hope I answered what you meant

Comment: @Marcos: protoc only generates the .java files, which you'd then need to compile in Netbeans. Did those all compile without any problems for you? Check for any compilation errors/warnings.

Comment: they were compiled..I can see the generated class files

Comment: @Marcos: Yes, the class file may be there - but it may have been *partially* compiled. Given that Eclipse has had the ability to do this for a while, I dare say Netbeans can do it now too. I wouldn't be surprised to find that a type initializer for Comment is throwing that exception.